# How to filter values from array and object comparison in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here, I have one object and one array I want to filter value comparing both array and object,

object have multiple values see in below code `Reader, Author, Publisher..`, in array `Author and Reader` I want to compare them and want this type of results of `wanted result :- [1, 8]`
this is my object

```
object1 = { 1: "Reader"
  8: "Author"
  3: "Publisher"
  9: "Site Editor"
  11: "Guest"
  12: "Editor"
  13: "Designer"
  14: "Publicist"
}
```

this is my array

```
array1 = ["Reader", "Author"]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. ... and what you have tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz I update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the keys of the object and check if the key has a value in the array using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const object1 = {
  1: "Reader",
  8: "Author",
  3: "Publisher",
  9: "Site Editor",
  11: "Guest",
  12: "Editor",
  13: "Designer",
  14: "Publicist"
};

const array1 = ["Reader", "Author"]

const keys = Object.keys(object1).filter(k => array1.includes(object1[k]))

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and return the values by using the switched key/value from the entries of the object.

The result are strings, because the keys of an object are either strings or symbols.

```js
var object = { 1: "Reader", 8: "Author", 3: "Publisher", 9: "Site Editor", 11: "Guest", 12: "Editor", 13: "Designer", 14: "Publicist" },
    array = ["Reader", "Author"],
    result = array.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        new Map(Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution might help you

```
 var values = Object.keys(object1).filter(key => {
   return array1.indexOf(object1[key]);
 });
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work ,with array filter ,map and find.

```js
object1 = { 1: "Reader",
  8: "Author",
  3: "Publisher",
  9: "Site Editor",
  11: "Guest",
  12: "Editor",
  13: "Designer",
  14: "Publicist",
}


array1 = ["Reader", "Author"]

let result=Object.values(object1)

let finalresult=array1.filter(ele=>result.includes(ele)).map(element=>Object.keys(object1).find(key => object1[key] === element))
console.log(finalresult)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the object and check if the value is present in the array1. If so then push the key to an array

```js
let obj = {
  1: "Reader",
  8: "Author",
  3: "Publisher",
  9: "Site Editor",
  11: "Guest",
  12: "Editor",
  13: "Designer",
  14: "Publicist",
}

let array1 = ["Reader", "Author"];
let newArry = [];

for (let keys in obj) {
  if (array1.includes(obj[keys])) {
    newArry.push(keys)
  }
}
console.log(newArry)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code can be helpful for you :

```
array1=[object1.1,object1.2]
```

the property object 1 is not array it is an object and each object has a property and value here in object1 '1' is a property and 'Reader' is value of this property and you can get each value of this object by dot and the name of property.